# Find and copy code

Tags: excel, find, vba

Right people, I’m back again for some more help. I have a workbook where I add new worksheets every month with information which is exactly the same as before in structure. In column A, I have invoice numbers then details from columns B:J. In columns K & L there are comments manually added for all outstanding issues. What I want to do is be able to lookup invoices against the last worksheet and then copy comments in columns K & L into the new worksheet.

I have tried to create a bit of code but nothing is coming off it. The ActiveSheet is the newly created without comments. So i want to lookup invoice numbers in columns A and copy columns K & L where a match is found from last worksheet to columns K&L of the activesheet. I hope I make sense and thank you for helping

```
Option Explicit

Sub FindCopy_all()

    Dim calc As Long
    Dim Cel As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim rFound As Range
    Dim LookRange As Range
    Dim CelValue As Variant

     ' Speed
    calc = Application.Calculation
    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

     'Get Last row of data ActiveSheet, Col A
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(1048576, 1).End(xlUp).Row

     ' Set range to look in
    Set LookRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" & LastRow)

     ' Loop on each value (cell)
    For Each Cel In LookRange
         ' Get value to find
        CelValue = Cel.Value
         ' Look on previous sheet
        With Sheets(Sheets.Count - 3)

            Set rFound = .Cells.Find(What:=CelValue, _
            After:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, _
            Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)

             ' Reset
            On Error GoTo endo

             ' Not found, go next
            If rFound Is Nothing Then
                GoTo NextCel
            Else
                 ' Found. last sheet, Col K & L to Active Sheet found Row, Col K & L
                .Cells(rFound.Row, 11, 12).Resize(, 2).Copy ActiveSheet.Cells(Cel.Row, 11, 12)
            End If
        End With
NextCel:
    Next Cel
Set rFound = Nothing

     'Reset

endo:

    With Application
        .Calculation = calc
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: is there a reason why you can't use a VLOOKUP formula in your target columns on the last worksheet to get the comments data matching what you want?

Comment: The only reason is that I want to automate processes and not spend time doing the formulas. I work for a small company with computer illiterate assistants and the easiest is to have a VBA code that does everything at the click of a button.

Comment: ok, but why not automate putting in the formula when the new sheet is added such as `Range("....").formula="=VLOOKUP(...)"` so the work will be done by a formula in the worksheet

Comment: I didn't want to tell the guy what to do ;) but thats a great idea and would be better performance then the ops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in a `with` statement on the previous sheet and no `activesheet` statement exist. Use:

```
.Cells(rFound.Row, 11).Resize(,2).Copy activesheet.Cells(cel.Row, 11)
```

**Also**, you shouldn't need `On Error Resume Next` as the range returned will be `nothing` and also be sure you `set  rFound = nothing` after you've completed each find.

```
NextCel:
set rFound = nothing
```

---

**my code:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub FindCopy_all()

    Dim calc As Long
    Dim Cel As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim rFound As Range
    Dim LookRange As Range
    Dim CelValue As Variant

     ' Speed
    calc = Application.Calculation
    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

     'Get Last row of data ActiveSheet, Col A
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(1048576, 1).End(xlUp).Row

     ' Set range to look in
    Set LookRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" & LastRow)

     ' Loop on each value (cell)
    For Each Cel In LookRange
         ' Get value to find
        CelValue = Cel.Value
         ' Look on previous sheet
        With Sheets(Sheets.Count - 1)

            Set rFound = .Range("A:A").Find(What:=CelValue, _
            After:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, _
            Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)

             ' Not found, go next
            If rFound Is Nothing Then
                GoTo NextCel
            Else
                 ' Found. last sheet, Col K & L to Active Sheet found Row, Col K & L
                .Cells(rFound.Row, 11).Resize(, 2).Copy ActiveSheet.Cells(Cel.Row, 11)
            End If
        End With
NextCel:
    Set rFound = Nothing
    Next Cel

    With Application
        .Calculation = calc
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. There is nothing copying from the previous sheet into the active sheet. Absolutely nothing. In addition I want to copy columns K&L where comments & actions are.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help the code is working, but its not matching what is being pasted to the correct row. Is there an adjustment that needs to be done to achive this?

Comment: Hello can someone help please. My code is working but not matching what its picking up from the old worksheet

Comment: what I mean is that when an invoice is found in the new sheet, the comments that belong to that invoice if it was in the preceding sheet are not being matched to it like you would get when a vlookup is done. To test I have taken exactly the same data from the preceding sheet into the new one exclusing columns K&L. But when I run the macro, the comments are not being matched to the invoice.

Comment: I would only search the invoice column and be sure the data has no spaces before or after ad you are using xlwhole

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Just to let you know, I'm a VBA noob and have only started coding in the last month. The answer you've given is complicated beyond my little understanding. I have updated my earlier post with my code as is. Is there a chance you could look at it and "mend" as it were; to what works. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @Werra2006 try my answer which puts in VLOOKUP formulas, then replaces them with ordinary text afterwards.

Comment: Got it to work now. My sheet reference was wrong so corrected that and that did the trick. Thank you all for the massive help, you are great people.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that your VBA code puts VLOOKUP formulas in the new worksheet to retrieve the invoice information like this:

`activesheet.Cells(cel.Row, 11).formula="=VLOOKUP(...)"`

then in order to replace the formulas with text your code could use

`activesheet.Cells(cel.Row, 11).Copy`

followed by

`activesheet.Cells(cel.Row, 11).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` to replace the formulas with just text values

try my code

```
 ' Speed
calc = Application.Calculation
With Application
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

 'Get Last row of data ActiveSheet, Col A
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(activesheet.rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

 ' Set VLOOKUP formula, search on the other sheet for the value in column A, return the value matchiung from column 11, and use EXACT MATCH.
'
' =VLOOKUP(A:A,Sheet1!A:L,11,FALSE) ' example
'
range("K1:K" & lastRow).formula="=VLOOKUP(A:A," & sheets(Worksheets.count-1).name & "!A:L,11, FALSE)"

activesheet.calculate
range("K1:K" & lastRow).copy
range("K1:K" & lastRow).pastespecial xlpastevalues ' remove the formulas
```

that should get you started, try stepping through that and check the VLOOKUP is acting on the right columns and let us know how you get on

Philip